# ios objective c todo app

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, breakpoints

I'm very new to objective c, xcode, and ios development in general. I am just trying to create a simple TODO app but I am not having luck with my check complete. Every time I click on an item, I get a (lldb) in the console log and a thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 that I dont know what its referring to. My breakpoint comes in at the last line `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` I'm not sure whats going on here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import "TDOViewController.h"

@interface TDOViewController () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;

@end

@implementation TDOViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // Handles list of items
    self.items =  @[@{@"name" : @"Take out the trash", @"category" : @"home"}, @{@"name" : @"Shoes", @"category" : @"home"}].mutableCopy;

    // Handles navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.title = @"To-Do List";

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewItem:)];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Adding Items
- (void)addNewItem:(UIBarButtonItem *) sender {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New ToDo Item" message:@"Enter name of new ToDo Item" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add Item", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        UITextField * itemNameField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        NSString *itemName = itemNameField.text;
        NSDictionary *item = @{@"name" : itemName, @"category" : @"home"};
        [self.items addObject:item];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.items.count - 1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TodoItemRow";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *item = self.items[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = item[@"name"];

    if ([item[@"completed"] boolValue]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableDictionary *item = [self.items[indexPath.row] mutableCopy];
    BOOL completed = [item[@"completed"] boolValue];
    item[@"completed"] = @(!completed);

    self.items[indexPath.row] = item;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = ([item[@"completed"] boolValue]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


@end
```

Comment: Do you have a little blue flag in the margin next to that line?  If so, then you have set a breakpoint on that line.  This asks the debugger to stop your app at that point so that you can check its execution and variables.  It is a powerful debugging tool.  Learn how to use it.  In the mean time, click the blue flag to disable it

Comment: Okay that makes sense. That is what the issue was. I didn't even notice that I had placed the debugger there and thus why I was confused as to why the program halted at the end. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on a line number in the margin will set a breakpoint, which stops execution of the program at runtime any time that line of code is due to execute.

This can be useful for finding errors in your code, but somewhat annoying if you place them accidentally. Simply clicking on the blue arrow will disable the breakpoint, clicking and dragging it off the margin will remove it.

You can also turn off breakpoints globally by disabling them in the console toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for this response. Very informative. I am following a tutorial and trying to make sense of the code. For the most part I am understanding what is going on. However, I do call, what seems to be a variable, `tableView` multiple times. Is this a standard variable for the actual view? I'm confused where it was defined.

Comment: A table view controller has a local property named tableView inherently. When adding a table view to a regular view controller, you will need to declare your own tableView property.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the breakpoints in Breakpoint Navigator. If you want to debug the code, please follow tis link "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html"

Hope its helpful.